# Installing ArcGIS Server 10 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arcgis, ubuntu-10.10, arcgis-server

Anyone who has the experience installing ArcGIS server 10 on Ubuntu 10.10. Is it possible doing that?

Comment: I'd really like to do this as well.

Comment: Why you don't try to install it?
I saw on online documentation, and I think it's requirement is generally provided on almost every linux distribution.

Comment: Please see this post on GIS-SE for a more up to date answer.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/arcgis-server-10-on-ubuntu-or-centos

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Windows, ArcGIS Server 10 is only supported on Redhat Ent., Sun Solaris, and SUSE. Sorry to burst your bubble! According to the [online documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/10.0/arcgis-server-server-requirements).